# How to bring back a removed display group in corona?

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, game-engine, game-development

I used this call in my code

display.remove(GroupName)

and it worked successfully, but how do I bring back the objects in the display object?

is there a command that will allow me to re-display the group?

Comment: If you want to re-display, you should NOT remove it, use `object.isVisible` instead.

Comment: recreate the object with same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you cant bring back something that you removed as it will be void. You can hide it if you want to have it back. You can use this instead:

GroupName.isVisible = false